# Decipher a list update audit entry

Tags: list, auditing

I'm looking at the audit log and when a contact is updated I see the very un-useful document location of Lists/Test List/1_.000.

Anyone know how to make sense of these cryptic entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those audit log entries are for list items. I can't tell you *why* they end up that way but I wrote some code that makes them pretty URLs:

```
const string LIST_ITEM_SUFFIX = "_.000";
if (docLocation.EndsWith(LIST_ITEM_SUFFIX))
{
   // this is a list item with the URL all garbled up at the end
   // does not seem to have anything to do with versioning
   StringBuilder newUrl = new StringBuilder(docLocation);
   newUrl.Remove(newUrl.Length - LIST_ITEM_SUFFIX.Length, LIST_ITEM_SUFFIX.Length);
   newUrl.Insert(docLocation.LastIndexOf("/") + 1, "DispForm.aspx?ID=");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view this list item by going to:

> http://yourSharePointsite/Lists/TestList/DispForm.aspx?ID=1

I'm not sure why but SharePoint spits out the useless URL that you posted when you try to get the ListItem url.

Breakdown:

TestList = List Name
1_.000 = ID of list item, with some extra garbage added